# How do I set a class variable from another class (Kivy/KivyMD)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So i am having trouble trying to set my button text from another class.

if you look at the function `set_people`, i use `PosScreen.people = name` to change the name, but the button text wont change. So i figured i have to acccess it via `ids` but im stuck on how to do it from another class. Here is my code:

test.py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

pos_dialog = None

class PosScreen(Screen):
    people = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PosScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.people = "No one"

    def close_dialog(self, *obj):
        global pos_dialog
        pos_dialog.dismiss()
        pos_dialog = None

    def open_people_dialog(self):
        global pos_dialog
        if not pos_dialog:
            pos_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Choose customer",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContentPosAddPeople(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="Close",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        on_release=self.close_dialog
                    )
                ]
            )
        pos_dialog.open()


class DialogContentPosAddPeople(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DialogContentPosAddPeople, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_list_people()

    def set_list_people(self, text="", search=False):
        peeps = ["Brian", "AJ", "Nick", "Kevin", "Howie"]

        def add_name_item(name):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                    "text": name,
                    "on_release": lambda x=name: self.set_people(x),
                }
            )

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for name in peeps:
            if search:
                if text.lower() in name.lower():
                    add_name_item(name)
            else:
                add_name_item(name)

    def set_people(self, name):
        global pos_dialog
        PosScreen.people = name # it changes the variable but button text doesn't change
        PosScreen.ids.people_button.text = name # Not accessible NoneType
        pos_dialog.dismiss()
        pos_dialog = None
        return


class testApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(PosScreen(name="pos"))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
PosScreen:

<PosScreen>:
    name: "pos"
    people_button: people_button
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 72/255, 72/255, 72/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RelativeLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                id: people_button
                icon: "account-circle-outline"
                text: root.people
                pos_hint:{'x': 0.05, 'center_y': 0.9}
                md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                on_release: root.open_people_dialog()


<DialogContentPosAddPeople>:
    rv: rv
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: dp(10)
    padding: dp(20)
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"
    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'magnify'
        MDTextField:
            id: search_field
            hint_text: 'Search name'
            on_text: root.set_list_people(self.text, True)
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
        key_size: 'height'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            padding: dp(10)
            default_size: None, dp(48)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

Expected result: When I click one of the names, it will close the dialog and change the button's text to the name that i picked

Can someone help me shed some light on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try using method [`get_screen`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen).

Comment: @ApuCoder well i can't access the screen from that class since it has different parent but i solved it by passing the screen when calling the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it by passing the screen object when calling the second class.

```
    class PosScreen(Screen):
        ...
    
        def open_people_dialog(self):
            global pos_dialog
            if not pos_dialog:
                pos_dialog = MDDialog(
                    ...
                    content_cls=DialogContentPosAddPeople(self), # Added self here
                    ...
                        )
                    ]
                )
            pos_dialog.open()
```

and in the called class:

```
class DialogContentPosAddPeople(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs): # Added master
        super(DialogContentPosAddPeople, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.master = master 

    def set_people(self, name): 
        self.master.people = name #Referencing the master
        self.master.ids.people_button.text = name
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Note on terminology: you aren't "passing the screen class". Instead, you are passing an **instance** of the screen class. Or alternatively you can say that you are passing a screen **object**.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying that. I still haven't get a full understanding of the class system. As a new self-thought programmer, my terminology is still super basic.